# Joining a collection and a List throws NotSupportedException in C# Mongodb strongly typed driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using the official C# MongoDb strongly typed driver version 2.8.0 to interact with MongoDB.

When I try to join a mongodb collection of type Meals with a list of type MealsRequest I get this exception:-

```
System.NotSupportedException: The joined collection cannot have any qualifiers."
```

Here is my code:-

```
public class Meal
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(representation: BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string RestaurantId { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public int Calories { get; set; }

    public string Photo { get; set; }
}

public class MealRequest
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(representation: BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string MealId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public decimal MealTotal { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the code that throws the exception:-

```
var mealsRequests = await repository.Meals.AsQueryable()
    .Join(inner: mealsRequests, outerKeySelector: m => m.Id, innerKeySelector: mr => mr.MealId,
    resultSelector: (m, mr) => new MealRequest()
    {
        Id = mr.Id,
        MealId = m.Id,
        Count = mr.Count,
        Price = m.Price,
        Name = m.Name,
    }).ToListAsync();//Exception happens at this line 

return mealsRequests;
```

And this is the stack trace:-

```
System.NotSupportedException: The joined collection cannot have any qualifiers.
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.Pipeline.MethodCallBinders.JoinBinder.Bind(PipelineExpression pipeline, PipelineBindingContext bindingContext, MethodCallExpression node, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.MethodInfoMethodCallBinder`1.Bind(PipelineExpression pipeline, TBindingContext bindingContext, MethodCallExpression node, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.Pipeline.PipelineBinder.Bind(Expression node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Prepare(Expression expression)
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Translate(Expression expression)
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryableImpl`2.ToCursorAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.ToListAsync[TDocument](IAsyncCursorSource`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

What is the cause of this exception? And how to resolve it?

Comment: I can't get this code to compile. `mealsRequests` is declared as the `var` but is used inside the declaration as part of the `inner` definition.

Comment: @PeteGarafano Rename the result var from mealsRequests to results, and for the inner definition of the inner mealsRequests is a List<MealRequest>

Answer (score 0):

relationships and navigation is extremely easy with [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities) which is a lightweight wrapper around the official driver. it is also async capable even though the following example is sync code.

```
using System.Linq;
using MongoDB.Entities;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Meal : Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Many<MealRequest> Requests { get; set; }

        public Meal() => this.InitOneToMany(() => Requests);
    }

    public class MealRequest : Entity
    {
        public One<Meal> Meal { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("retaurant-test");

            var meal = new Meal { Name = "pollo e funghi pasta" };
            meal.Save();

            var mealRequest = new MealRequest
            {
                Name = "pasta meal",
                Meal = meal.ToReference()
            };
            mealRequest.Save();

            meal.Requests.Add(mealRequest);

            var chickenMushroomPastaMealRequests = DB.Collection<MealRequest>()
                                                     .Where(mr => mr.Meal.ID == meal.ID)
                                                     .ToList();

            var resMealRequests = meal.Requests.Collection().ToList();

            var resMeal = resMealRequests.First().Meal.ToEntity();
        }
    }
}
```

if it must be done using the official driver, i'd do it using linq as follows:

```
var mealrequests = (from m in repo.Meals.AsQueryable()
                    join mr in repo.MealRequests.AsQueryable() on m.ID equals mr.MealID into requests
                    from r in requests
                    select r).ToList();
```

Comment: Could you provide the reason of this exception? And how to resolve it using the official driver?

Comment: @Waxren i've updated my answer above to show how to do it using the official driver. as for the cause of the exception, i'm not exactly sure. so i'll leave it up to someone else to answer :-)